# div moves when zoom in/out in all browsers

Tags: css

I have a following div structure

```
<div class="usrbox">
    <form method='post' action="index.php?e=67">
        <input type='hidden' name="index" value="34">
        <input type='hidden' name="id" value="1074580">
        <p>
            <input type='image' width=10 height=10 src="/images/ok.gif" border=0 title="ok" align='bottom'>
        </p>
    </form>
</div>
```

now when i zoom in or out from the browser, "usrbox" moves right / left ...

looking for help here very badly.

```
.usrbox {
    font-size: medium;
    position: relative;
    left: 30em;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You gave a left offset in `em`. Since that unit is relative to the font wize (which changes upon zoom) the box moves.

Comment: This. And in fact, this is exactly what most people are aiming for when using `em`s. Scaling to the browser's font-size is a feature (and a great one at that), not a bug.